# Error response from daemon: EOF on remove image

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I receive the error `Error response from daemon: EOF` when trying to remove an image with the command `docker rmi 07f8e8c5e660`. I've tried the force option with the same result.

I'm doing all of this within a docker machine having setup the machine and set my environment with the commands:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
```

Running on a Mac with OS X Yosemite.  Docker version:

```
Client version: 1.6.0
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 4749651
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.6.0
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 4749651
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

I've tried restarting docker:

```
boot2docker stop
boot2docker start
<set variables>
eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
```

But I still get the error when I try to remove the image.

I can create a new machine and start over but this machine has issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning Docker, but what worked for me in this situation was to pull the image again with `docker pull <image>`. At that point you can remove it without issues, if that's what you want. Hope this helps:

```
$ docker run tomcat:7
Error response from daemon: EOF

$ docker pull tomcat:7
7: Pulling from library/tomcat
141f200a609c: Pull complete 
78af5c127529: Pull complete 
00f6930c0831: Pull complete 
0ffc41dcdb30: Pull complete 
d2428219250d: Pull complete 
47297c3ce14f: Pull complete 
7afa3cfe7b5b: Pull complete 
843e2bded498: Already exists 
8c00acfb0175: Already exists 
8b49fe88b40b: Already exists 
3bdf542c6cd7: Already exists 
6bc56fdd5d30: Already exists 
65c0e7a8ee08: Already exists 
69d701da3d27: Already exists 
3360f01309dd: Already exists 
6e7a2279985d: Already exists 
21c22bddbd60: Already exists 
5d6dc56636f2: Already exists 
64b19662bd12: Already exists 
library/tomcat:7: The image you are pulling has been verified. Important: image verification is a tech preview feature and should not be relied on to provide security.
Digest: sha256:b545868782d6cbae48a1d585cd3bc9ed1de44993c2c8261e495aa6ac67d45462
Status: Downloaded newer image for tomcat:7

$ docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
tomcat                    7                   7afa3cfe7b5b        6 

$ docker rmi -f 7afa3cfe7b5b
Untagged: tomcat:7
Deleted: 7afa3cfe7b5b83fd4b001e15aaec8070de1f792a2c6c72c6e7c34b834fbcce37
Deleted: 47297c3ce14f196ac1a2c8dd73c97f76acd3e8dac400b127cc094527a8ac15b2
Deleted: d2428219250d54fd8f0983fd1053957ce93a8966b2197df407d91c2d9c59dc96
Deleted: 0ffc41dcdb30734cc8119a17fae5b480fd0557f7ef49b3ddeddab1e576101f3b
Deleted: 00f6930c0831bb7d276405b6f77767a26ac982ed52a892e4c6f079c8b450b65c
Deleted: 78af5c1275296c92f03800d9e540fc83e4fef5c7616a226576f3250b1fb0f5e8
Deleted: 141f200a609cc59568b33705dd4222c5f41a9bc17094e6c36e181f581254c156
```